# My Dialog in Material ui Angular don't function

Tags: angular, angular-material, dialog

I tried to use dialog from material UI, the problem is the alert don't recognize material classes. Is like to don't import the material UI, `mat-button`, `mat-dialog-close` and others don't function. Only the angular flex-layout it's ok.

[image: Don't recognize the material classes]

I copied the code from this example: [Example dialog](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/examples)

Code in my TS:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {MatDialog} from '@angular/material/dialog';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-norma-adscripcion',
  templateUrl: './norma-adscripcion.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./norma-adscripcion.component.css']
})
export class NormaAdscripcionComponent {
  //DIALOG ALERT
  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {}

  openDialog() {
    this.dialog.open(NormaAdscripcionDialogComponent);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-norma-adscripcion-dialog',
  templateUrl: './norma-adscripcion-dialog.component.html',
})
export class NormaAdscripcionDialogComponent {}
```

Code in **norma-adscripcion.component.html**:

```
<div fxLayout="column" class="mx-3">
    <h1>Cambio Adscripcion (Norma)</h1>
    <button  mat-raised-button color="primary"  mat-button (click)="openDialog()">EXIT</button> 
</div>
```

Comment: Are you importing the `ButtonModule` from `@angular/material/button` in your module?

Answer (score 0):

I solved that, the problem was I called a only "HTML", but I need to call a another component, no only a html. I only haved a html, but I created the component and that is solve.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-norma-adscripcion-dialog',
  templateUrl: './norma-adscripcion-dialog.component.html',
})
```